# Scheduling an event in AlarmManager on android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have already read some tutorials and read the documentation, but I can't make this work... This is what I have been testing:

This is the way I register the intent to be called with the alarm manager:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1)

PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

My AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, NewCommit.class);
        context.startActivity(intent2);
    }   
}
```

And of course I added the receiver in the androidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:process=":remote"  android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

And is INSIDE the application tag.

Any idea? It's driving me crazy, I can't find what's wrong!

Thanks

Comment: At first glance, everything looks fine, how do you call this code? is it in `onCreate()`, via a button, or...?

Comment: via a button in the main activity... It's driving me crazy...

Comment: For *debugging* purposes, move the code to `onCreate()`.

Comment: not working neither... =(

Comment: I think you have to set up an intent handler for this, if I remember correctly.

Comment: there is an intent when I create the pendingIntent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added to the intent from pendingIntent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I hope in helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```

Comment: I think that permission is just for using AlarmClock provider (android.provider.AlarmClock), not for settings Alarms.